# Web page is really slow in Chrome when inspector is open but *not* profiling

Tags: google-chrome, rxjs, google-chrome-devtools, ngxs

In my Angular application, after introducing some more heavy usage of ngxs, I see my application has been come very slow **when the inspector is open**, but **not when the profiler is running**.

This has made it a little hard to figure out what's going on, but using the old `conosle.profile` method (adding an entry to Chrome's old profiler), I've narrowed it down a little - but I'm not at all more informed now than I was - just more confused.

So here's to hoping someone here can help me out!

I have some screenshots from the profiling to share, but unfortunately not much else.

First, a screenshot from the profile chart:
[image]
As you can see, there's a looooong time, where apparently nothing is really happening. Note in the console, that the bottom method (`startObserving`) only takes .12ms (according to `console.time`)

Going up the tree a few steps, we find `Handsontable` - this is what the function looks like, and some timings associated:

```
function Handsontable(rootElement, userSettings) {
  console.time('Handsontable total time');
  console.time('Handsontable create instance');
  var instance = new _core2.default(rootElement, userSettings || {}, _rootInstance.rootInstanceSymbol);
  console.timeEnd('Handsontable create instance');
  console.time('Handsontable init instance');
  instance.init();
  console.timeEnd('Handsontable init instance');
  console.timeEnd('Handsontable total time');
  return instance;
}

// Timer outputs:
// This looks OK
Handsontable create instance: 10.864990234375ms
// Also this
Handsontable init instance: 1462.807861328125ms
// Wow, what??
Handsontable total time: 52664.875ms
```

It looks like the 2 methods called in the `Handsontable` constructor/function have a total run-time of <1500ms, but the total execution time is more than 52 **seconds**.

What in the world can be happening in those ~50 seconds of - as I see it - idle time?

Any help is really welcome, hints, suggestions, help to better debug!

Note: In Firefox, this is not an issue. I've tried in Chromium 67, 68 and 69 too - same issue. It's a problem in Chrome across all platforms (tested in Windows 10, Ubuntu 16,17 and MacOS latest-1,latest)

Comment: Could be a bug in Chrome so I suggest checking the [older versions](https://github.com/henrypp/chromium/tags).

Comment: One of my colleagues suggested this as well, but seeing that 67 is from april, and this issue hasn't been aroung for more than a few months, I stopped pursuing that path

Comment: After digging a little deeper, it seems that if I replace my ngxs store with a simple class with a BehaviourSubject, everything works just fine. So I guess there's an issue somewhere in ngxs